How Can I Resolve the 'Cannot load ruleset' and 'XPathRule' Class Error in PMD?
C:\Users\deniz\Desktop\OZU\CS401\dontUpdateA>pmd check -d src -R customRuleset.xml -f text
[ERROR] Error at customRuleset.xml:11:11
  9 |          language="java"
 10 |          message="Message explaining the rule"
 11 |          class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule"
               ^^^^^ net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule

 12 |        <description>Rule description</description>
 13 |        <priority>3</priority>: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule
[ERROR] Cannot load ruleset customRuleset.xml: An XML validation error occurred
[WARN] Progressbar rendering conflicts with reporting to STDOUT. No progressbar will be shown. Try running with argument -r <file> to output the report to a file instead.

I keep receiving this error whatever I do, I believe the issue is caused by the class attribute but I couldn't figure what to do. Below, I put the xml file of the custom ruleset.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="CustomRuleset">

    <description>This is a custom ruleset.</description>

    <rule name="CustomRuleExample"
          language="java"
          message="Message explaining the rule"
          class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule">
        <description>Rule Description</description>
        <priority>3</priority>
        <properties>
            <property name="xpath">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[
                    //VariableDeclaratorId[string-length(@Image) < 2]
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </rule>
</ruleset>

I tried changing the class value to everything but the problem is not solved. I appreciate if you respond.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The ruleset was written for PMD 6 and you are using now PMD 7. There are some incompatibilities, which are described in the Migration Guide for PMD 7.
Most notably for your case:

the class XPathRule has been moved into package net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.xpath (see https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_migrating_to_pmd7.html#xpath-rules)
The Java AST has been changed significantly. Your XPath expression needs to be adjusted, so that it finds some violations.

E.g. the node "VariableDeclatorId" has been renamed to "VariableId" (https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_migrating_to_pmd7.html#renamed-classes--interfaces)
Using @Image should be avoided - instead use @Name for the variable name (https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_migrating_to_pmd7.html#java)



Alternatively, you can download the latest 6.x version from GitHub, which is PMD 6.55.0 and use this version instead of the latest PMD 7 - then you don't need to migrate your ruleset.
